# How to render UIView into 2 parts

Tags: iphone, render, transition, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I am trying to develop transition effect, when one view splits into 2 parts with upper part animated upwards and lower part animated downwards  to revel the view behind it.
I am using UIView and UIImageView approach to accomplish that:

```
// 1. Make a screenshot:
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.frame.size);
    [parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // 2. Calculate rectangles for top and bottom part:
    CGRect rectTop, rectBottom;
    CGFloat W = rectBig.size.width;
    CGFloat H = rectBig.size.height;


    rectTop = CGRectMake(0, 0, W, y_cutoff);
    rectBottom = CGRectMake(0, y_cutoff, W, H - y_cutoff);

    // 3. Create top and bottom images:
    CGImageRef imageRefTop      = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], rectTop);
    CGImageRef imageRefBottom   = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], rectBottom);


    UIImage *imageTop = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefTop];
    UIImage *imageBottom = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefBottom];


// 4. Assign images to image views:
imageViewTop.image = imageTop;
imageViewBottom.image = imageBottom;

// 5. Animate image views:
[UIView beginAnimation:nil context:NULL];
.... animation code here
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code however, is extremely slow on the device and I am sure there is a more efficient way to implement such a transition. Most probably using CALayers, etc..
Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: What does "extremely slow" mean?  Where does Instruments say it's spending its time?

Comment: Transition is fired when front view is clicked. After click there is noticeable delay and animation itself is jerky (tested on iPhone 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not animation. Your drawing code is slow. If you profile, you will see that `renderInContext:` (btw. always executed on the main thread) and `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` are the limiting factors. What your view (the one you want to split) is about? Is it an option to create two views instead of one from start?

Comment: You are right. Profiling shows a lot of effort in the renderInContext method. But my view cannot be divided as it is some king of grid menu with UIScrollView. It divides at the dynamic point (touch point) when user taps on it.

Answer (score 2):

The animation itself shouldn't be slow. All you really need to be doing is changing the Y position of the two views for the animation.

Why don't you try putting static images into the UIImageViews and seeing how the animation performs then?

If the lag is happening when you are creating the images, maybe you should consider moving that code to a separate thread so that the main thread doesn't freeze up. When the images are done being created, notify the main thread, put them in the UIImageViews, and perform the animation.